# Imitating stingray-skin texture?

Tags: material-selection, leather, props

I am working on a Saihai-prop for a LARP and I want to wrap it in a way that imitates a Stingray skin on the handle. However some stingray skins can't be traded legally under the Washington treaty, so I need to substitute for the real stuff. I technically could buy pearl-ray skin, which is legal, but that would mean I need to get a lot more of the leather than I actually need: the handle only is about 150 mm long and about 50 mm in circumference.

How can I make an imitation of the bubbly texture of rounded domes that is characteristic for a stingray skin, which can then be wrapped around a wooden handle?

Answer (score 4):

- A rather natural and realistic looking imitation you can opt for, is **real leather that has been made to look like stingray leather**. This is [bonded leather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonded_leather), and made by pressing leather scraps mixed with a binder, often rubber. This specific imitation is quite hard to find, though.
- There are also **faux leather** alternatives (polyurethane and PVC) to this.

| [image] | [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bonded leather ([source](https://bestbeads.com/10mm-fauxstingray)) | Faux leather (i.c. PU) ([source](https://www.etsy.com/au/listing/832545762/pu-leather-fabric-faux-leatherette?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=faux%20stingray%20leather&ref=sr_gallery-1-7&from_market_listing_grid_organic=1)) | Silicone mold ([source](https://sweetybijou.com/silicone-texture-stingray-skin-leather-180x115mm/)) |

- Alternatively, you might be able to create a material with the texture of stingray leather using a [silicone mold](https://sweetybijou.com/silicone-texture-stingray-skin-leather-180x115mm/).
  For a pliable material, you can cast with silicone (be sure to use a release agent; see also [this question](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/4279/replicating-a-silicone-object)), or polymer clay, as Elmy suggests in the comments.
  You can dye the material, and probably - I haven't tried this, and it might not work well with a surface that will be *handle*d a lot - roughen it up using sandpaper, so it loses a little more of its sheen in order for it to be more leather-like in appearance.

  If you want to use latex instead of silicone, you have to make your own negative mold (creating a positive silicone mold and using plaster to create a negative one, for example).
- For a cheaper method, you might be able to stamp an anti-slip material, which regularly come with tiny domes on their surface (see image below), onto clay to create a mold.

  [image]
  <sup>[source](https://ws.draadrianabarbachan.com.uy/)</sup>

Comment: Please be aware that the "silicone texture" is a silicone mat with the negative texture, designed to imprint polymer clay and other soft materials. You do not get the leather-like pieces that are held in the hand, but the light blue mat in the background.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @Elmy! I will mend it later.

Comment: It still is a viable option for OP if they're ok with wrapping the handle in polymer clay instead of a textile. And properly cured polymer clay might stay intact longer than faux leather, which often plits into its individual layers after prolonged skin contact.

Comment: Neat ideas, but oddly enough, that actually costs more than the pearl-ray leather as rests @.@

Comment: @Trish I was writing a comment, and suddenly thought of something else and added it: might the last option in my answer help suppress the price?